# I need to click an event through a loop in JS

Tags: javascript

I'm new in JavaScript.In my small project I need users to click a button everytime the loop iterates.But in actual case it is not happening.

```
INPUT: <input id="input" >
<button id="btn">Play</button>

  <script>
        const btn = document.querySelector('#btn');
        const inp = document.querySelector('#input');
        for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
            let x = inp.value;
            console.log(x);
            console.log(i);
});
        }

   </script>
```

I tried while loop too! What should i do? please help!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're only _setting an event listener_ on the button, not _clicking_ the button. I suggest that you should take a look at [Creating and triggering events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) from the MDN documentation.

Comment: Why would you need to click a button a number of times? That doesn't really seem to be what intended functionality would be. Can you explain your situation in greater detail?

Comment: I still don't understand what you're intending to do by clicking the button multiple times, unless I'm interpreting your question incorrectly.

Comment: @JoelHager Brother it's like a guessing game. User will type a number and click the button then random generator will generate a random number. Then we will check user guess vs Computer generated guess. But ** I want to do it 10 times or N times. **  So i need a loop to iterate and in each iteration take user input.

Comment: Right - But you don't *need* a click to do that. The click is a *user* event; not a computer one. There's no need for the computer to be 'clicking' buttons.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've mentioned in my comment, you're only *setting an event listener* (with `addEventListener`) on the button, not *clicking* the button.

Instead, you should create a new event with the [`Event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) constructor, then call [`EventTarget#dispatchEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent) on the element with the event as the argument:

```js
const button = document.getElementById('button');
const input = document.getElementById('input');

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  const event = new Event('click');
  button.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

Alternatively, you should use the [`HTMLElement#click`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click) method, which simulates a mouse click on an element:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  button.click();
}
```

(P.S. While you're at it, I suggest that you should use [`Document#getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) if you want to retrieve an element by its unique ID instead of [`Document#querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).)

Answer (score 0):

For such a case, you would rather do a recursion

```
INPUT: <input id="input" >
<button id="btn">Play</button>

  <script>
        const btn = document.querySelector('#btn');
        const inp = document.querySelector('#input');
        var i=0;
            btn.addEventListener('click', function(evt){
                        let x = inp.value;
                        console.log(x);
                        console.log(i);
                        if(i<10){
                                    i++;
                        }else{
                                    evt.target.removeEventListener();
                        }
            });


   </script>
```

As you can see here, I add an event listener that takes care of incrementing value of `i` until it reaches 10. Then, it simply removes the event listener - similar to ending the loop.

Comment: Why you call it recursion?

Comment: Every time event occurs, the same function keeps getting called until you explicitly remove the event. Its not exactly a recursion of the kind you would see in Java codes

Comment: I understand your point, but in my opinion It's not recursion at all. Or maybe I just misinterpret english term.